# HAProxy Domain / Subdomain ACL rule

Tags: proxy, load-balancing, haproxy

I'm trying to setup HAProxy for 1 Domain and 1 Subdomain.
The actual situation is that:

```
Internet -> pfSense Firewall -> HAProxy -> SRV1 (192.168.100.1) domain.com
                                        -> SRV2 (192.168.100.2) srv2.domain.com
```

Actually it IS working - I can access SRV1 if I type domain.com and I can access SRV2 if I type srv2.domain.com.. BUT:
If I open my Browser and type domain.com and open a new tab with srv2.domain.com, the 2nd tab (srv2) points me to domain.com instead of srv2.domain.com.. Same happens vice versa.. If I first browse to srv2.domain.com and then browse to domain.com, it points me to srv2.. So I always have to restart my browser if I want to browse to SRV1 and to SRV2..

here's my HAProxy config:

```
acl host_srv2 hdr_dom(host) -i srv2.domain.com
acl host_domain hdr_dom(host) -i domain.com

use_backend srv2 if host_srv2
use_backend domain if host_domain

backend srv2
balance roundrobin
option httpclose
option forwardfor
cookie JSESSIONID prefix
server srv2 192.168.100.2:80 check

backend domain
balance roundrobin
option httpclose
option forwardfor
cookie JSESSIONID prefix
server domain 192.168.100.1:80 check
```

do you have any Ideas?

Comment: Do you have any logs you could share? Of particular interest would be [fields 4 (frontend_name) and 5 (backend_name '/' server_name)](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#8.2.3)

Answer (score 4):

Change your acl's to:

```
acl host_domain hdr_dom(host) -i domain.com
acl host_server hdr_dom(host) -i srv2.domain.com
```

`

Once the first match hits it will skip remaining acl